# Two-state Hamiltonian matrix in basis

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, hamiltonian

I have a homework problem as following:

Write the two-state Hamiltonian matrix in a certain basis |1>, |2> in a general form as

\begin{array}{ccc}
H_{11} & H_{12}  \\
H_{21} & H_{22}  \end{array}

Impose hermiticity of H.

I'm wondering how to approach this problem? If I know the operator in terms of |1>,|2>, I can construct the elements in this matrix, by using $<e_{m}|H|e_{n}>$. I'm also confused about the wording here.

Can anyone give a clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have been given the explicit forms of the Hamiltonian $H$ and basis vectors $\vert j \rangle$, then you should compute the matrix elements directly as you suggested: $H_{ij} = \langle i \vert H \vert j \rangle$. However, based on the wording of the question, I suspect that this isn't the case. When the questions says that you need to "impose hermiticity of H", it means that the form you write the matrix in needs to exhibit hermiticity manifestly, i.e. it should be obvious from the notation. It's hard to give you a hint beyond that without just saying the answer, but I'll say this: the Hermiticity property $H = H^\dagger$ imposes a relationship among certain matrix elements of $H$. Since there is a single constraint on the matrix elements, the number of free matrix elements is reduced to three (in the same sense that providing a relational equality among four variables reduces the number of free variables to three). Therefore, you should only need to compute three of the $H_{ij}$ for your final matrix.

Answer (score 0):

It seens that your question is about how to construct the $H$ matrix
,so since $<e_{i}|e_{j}> = \delta_{ij} $ and $H_{ij} = <e_{i}|H|e_{j}>$ you can use then to construct $H$ such ,
    $H=\epsilon (|e_{1}><e_{1}|+|e_{1}><e_{2}|+|e_{2}><e_{1}|+|e_{2}><e_{2}|)$

The coefficient doesn't need to be one , let assume $|\psi> =a|e_{1}> + b|e_{2}>$

if we apply  $H$ on $|\psi>$ we'll get

$ H|\psi> = \epsilon (|e_{1}><e_{1}|+|e_{1}><e_{2}|+|e_{2}><e_{1}|+|e_{2}><e_{2}|)(a|e_{1}> + b|e_{2}>)$

$H|\psi>=\epsilon [a+b](|e_{1}>+|e_{2}>)$ and form example

$<e_{1}|H|\psi> = \epsilon[a+b]$, and wee have that $H|\psi>=E|\psi>$

$E.a=\epsilon[a+b] $ so we get that $a=\frac{b}{E-\epsilon}$

Fallowing the same steps you can find b an construct your $H$

Comment: But the coefficient for each part of H is not necessarily one.

Comment: Do we also need to put |1>,|2> into matrix at last?

Comment: I not quite sure if a understood you doubt , but I edited the answer , and you can take a look on a similar problem on Griffiths's Introduction to Quantum Mechanics ,in the second edition is the problem 3.23